# relationship with ArrayList and jTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Hej.
There is a collection with data.

```
static ArrayList<MyBeans> all = new ArrayList<MyBeans>();
```

There is a jTableModel too which invoke this table on jFrame.

```
TableModel model = new Table(all);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

For example, at some moment `ArrayList<MyBeans> all` was changed. What should do for change this table too?

Comment: you should read the documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: You should only make changes through the table model itself since it *should* have methods that fire the appropriate notification events when its data nucleus gets changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your all `ArrayList<MyBeans>` (which by the way should ***not*** be static) is the nucleus of a TableModel, then your problem is that you're trying to make changes directly to the ArrayList which you should never do. Instead you should make changes only by calling public methods in your TableModel, and these methods should fire the appropriate AbstractTableModel notification method that will notify any registered listeners (here, the displayed JTable itself) of any changes to its model.